# Turn off AppEngine (Java) sessions for certain requests

Tags: google-app-engine, session

We're using [sessions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions) in our GAE/J application. Over the weekend, we had a large spike in our datastore writes that appears to have been caused by a large number of _ah_SESSION entities being created (about 100-200 every minute). Near as we can tell, there was a rogue task queue creating them because they stopped when we purged the queue. The task was part of a [mapper](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) process we run hourly.

We don't need sessions in that hourly mapper (or indeed in any of our task queues or cron jobs or many other requests). Is there a way to disable creating a session for selected URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that can not be done.

This is particularly nasty when you have a non-browser clients (devices via REST or mapreduce jobs) where every request generates a new `_ah_SESSION` entity in the database.

The only way to avoid this is to write your own session handler: e.g. a servlet filter that sets/checks cookies and set it so that it ignores certain paths.

EDIT:

I just realized that there *could* be another way: make sure your client (mapreduce job) sets a dummy cookie with a proper name. GAE uses cookies named `ACSID` in production and `dev_appserver_login` on dev server. Just use always the same cookie value, so all requests will be treated as one user/session.

There will still be overhead of looking-up/saving session objects, but at least it will not create countless `_ah_SESSION` entities.

Comment: Thanks Peter. We'll go with a custom handler.